# How to open excel file from weka

Tags: excel, csv, weka

How to convert from excel to csv  to opened with weka "arff file"?
I know that i should save file in csv"coma delimeted"
and open iy with weka >>> but my problem when i do that 
i see all attrubite convert to one attribute with nominal
value >>> please give me hint

Input data :

```
@relation weather

@attribute outlook {sunny, overcast, rainy}
@attribute temperature real
@attribute humidity real
@attribute windy {TRUE, FALSE}
@attribute play {yes, no}

@data
sunny,85,85,FALSE,no
sunny,80,90,TRUE,no
overcast,83,86,FALSE,yes
rainy,70,96,FALSE,yes
rainy,68,80,FALSE,yes
rainy,65,70,TRUE,no
overcast,64,65,TRUE,yes
sunny,72,95,FALSE,no
sunny,69,70,FALSE,yes
rainy,75,80,FALSE,yes
sunny,75,70,TRUE,yes
overcast,72,90,TRUE,yes
overcast,81,75,FALSE,yes
rainy,71,91,TRUE,no
```

Comment: Cold you post an example of input and output?

Answer (score 2):

After exporting your data from Excel to CSV, open it in a plain text editor (e.g. Notepade++) and make sure that numeric data does **not** have any *quotation mark*. Then import the final CSV to Weka and it should work.